# invoke orientation changes on viewdidload

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

how to invoke method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) || 
    (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

in viewdidload.
the first view shouldn't change to landscape,and the second view should able to change to landscape.however,when i change landscape in second view and return to first view,the first view remain in landscape until i rotate the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may post a notification manually:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: doesn't work anyway.i found this from another room.UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[self presentModalViewController:c animated:NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[c release];
it works.

Comment: Probably because you call it from `viewDidLoad`, which is not called again when you pop your second view. If you call it from `viewDidAppear`it should work. I think it's a better solution than presenting and dismissing a view controller. However, if you like your solution post it as answer and accept it.